# asp.net core - stuck in authentication loop

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

if I configure authentication with

```
.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

all works fine, but if I configure it

```
        .AddAuthentication(options => {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
```

Even after a succesful login, the user gets redirected to the logon page.
I would expect the same behavior for both configs. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I mixed using identity framework and custom claims/cookies. When I kicked out the use of the identityframework. It all worked as expected.

See more in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846770/asp-net-core-identity-does-not-redirect-to-correct-logon-pages) case.