# ASP.NET Core Identity does not redirect to correct logon pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-configuration

Configured this way it is not working.

```
    services
        .AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

            options.LoginPath = $"/logon";
            options.LogoutPath = $"/logoff";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/accessdenied";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        })
```

configured this way it is working :

```
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "Caldr.Auth";
        options.LoginPath = $"/logon";
        options.LogoutPath = $"/logoff";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/accessdenied";
    });

    services
        .AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

I would expect both to have the same behavior. Apprantly not. Bug or I did not got how to configure it ? :-)

Any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of posting my question I had identity framework configured/added too. So it might have been the mix of several factors that may it not work properly.

The working solution:

CONFIG:

```
var authenticationBuilder = services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = $"/logon";
        options.LogoutPath = $"/logoff";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/accessdenied";
    });
ConfigureSocialLogins(authenticationBuilder);
```

The actual logon (i.e. writing the cookies is done via)

```
private async Task SignInUser(AppUser appUser)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, appUser.Email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, appUser.Displayname ?? appUser.Email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, appUser.Email),
            };
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, claimsPrincipal, new AuthenticationProperties());
        }
```

Take note of all the usages of CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme.